# It is possible to revive an objects grid position from an xaml in wpf grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I'm building an application which will be very similar to the know game "Game of Life" I'm not very experienced with wither C# xaml or wpf of the time being but i believe this will be a good way to learn it all better. Thus there will be struggles on the way.

I have made a 10x10 grid an filed it with buttons and each button have there place in the grid. To keep track of each generation i amuse i have to keep track the buttons position in the grid. So i thought, if i can use each buttons grid position Y-axis & X-axis. It would not be to hard to make simple method to irritate thorough each button and compare the positions within two foor loops, one for each axis.

I've tried to revive a buttons grid position with biding but i have not manage to get it working.

If it's possible to get a buttons grid potion from a grid, how do i do?
Is the a better way to approach my goal for the sake of good practice?

--
Code behind.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using GOL.GameGrid;
using GOL.GameGrid.Props;

namespace GOL
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for frmGame.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class frmGame : Window
    {

        string HelloWorld = "Hello World";
        private string btnDataContext;
        public frmGame()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MyBtnProps btnContent = new MyBtnProps() { Name = "T" };
            btnCollection();
        }
    private void btnReturn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var newW = new MainWindow();
        newW.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
    private void btnCollection()
    {
        MyBtnProps btnDataContext = new MyBtnProps() { IsAlive = "T" };
        //btn00.DataContext = btnDataContext;
        var btnCollection = new List<Button>();
        #region Grid Buttons added to collection.
        btnCollection.Add(btn01);
        btnCollection.Add(btn01);
        btnCollection.Add(btn02);
        btnCollection.Add(btn03);
        btnCollection.Add(btn04);
        btnCollection.Add(btn05);
        btnCollection.Add(btn06);
        btnCollection.Add(btn07);
        btnCollection.Add(btn08);
        btnCollection.Add(btn09);

        btnCollection.Add(btn10);
        btnCollection.Add(btn11);
        btnCollection.Add(btn12);
        btnCollection.Add(btn13);
        btnCollection.Add(btn14);
        btnCollection.Add(btn15);
        btnCollection.Add(btn16);
        btnCollection.Add(btn17);
        btnCollection.Add(btn18);
        btnCollection.Add(btn19);

        btnCollection.Add(btn20);
        btnCollection.Add(btn21);
        btnCollection.Add(btn22);
        btnCollection.Add(btn23);
        btnCollection.Add(btn24);
        btnCollection.Add(btn25);
        btnCollection.Add(btn26);
        btnCollection.Add(btn27);
        btnCollection.Add(btn28);
        btnCollection.Add(btn29);

        btnCollection.Add(btn30);
        btnCollection.Add(btn31);
        btnCollection.Add(btn32);
        btnCollection.Add(btn33);
        btnCollection.Add(btn34);
        btnCollection.Add(btn35);
        btnCollection.Add(btn36);
        btnCollection.Add(btn37);
        btnCollection.Add(btn38);
        btnCollection.Add(btn39);

        btnCollection.Add(btn40);
        btnCollection.Add(btn41);
        btnCollection.Add(btn42);
        btnCollection.Add(btn43);
        btnCollection.Add(btn44);
        btnCollection.Add(btn45);
        btnCollection.Add(btn46);
        btnCollection.Add(btn47);
        btnCollection.Add(btn48);
        btnCollection.Add(btn49);

        btnCollection.Add(btn50);
        btnCollection.Add(btn51);
        btnCollection.Add(btn52);
        btnCollection.Add(btn53);
        btnCollection.Add(btn54);
        btnCollection.Add(btn55);
        btnCollection.Add(btn56);
        btnCollection.Add(btn57);
        btnCollection.Add(btn58);
        btnCollection.Add(btn59);

        btnCollection.Add(btn60);
        btnCollection.Add(btn61);
        btnCollection.Add(btn62);
        btnCollection.Add(btn63);
        btnCollection.Add(btn64);
        btnCollection.Add(btn65);
        btnCollection.Add(btn66);
        btnCollection.Add(btn67);
        btnCollection.Add(btn68);
        btnCollection.Add(btn69);

        btnCollection.Add(btn70);
        btnCollection.Add(btn71);
        btnCollection.Add(btn72);
        btnCollection.Add(btn73);
        btnCollection.Add(btn74);
        btnCollection.Add(btn75);
        btnCollection.Add(btn76);
        btnCollection.Add(btn77);
        btnCollection.Add(btn78);
        btnCollection.Add(btn79);

        btnCollection.Add(btn80);
        btnCollection.Add(btn81);
        btnCollection.Add(btn82);
        btnCollection.Add(btn83);
        btnCollection.Add(btn84);
        btnCollection.Add(btn85);
        btnCollection.Add(btn86);
        btnCollection.Add(btn87);
        btnCollection.Add(btn88);
        btnCollection.Add(btn89);

        btnCollection.Add(btn90);
        btnCollection.Add(btn91);
        btnCollection.Add(btn92);
        btnCollection.Add(btn93);
        btnCollection.Add(btn94);
        btnCollection.Add(btn95);
        btnCollection.Add(btn96);
        btnCollection.Add(btn97);
        btnCollection.Add(btn98);
        btnCollection.Add(btn99);
        #endregion Buttons added to collection.


        foreach (var item in btnCollection)
        {
            item.DataContext = btnDataContext;
            btn01.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 102, 255, 179));
            btn00.Background = Brushes.Cornsilk;

            if (btn00.Background == Brushes.Cornsilk)
            {
                btn01.Background = Brushes.Azure;
            }
            else
            {
                btn01.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 102, 120, 255));
            }

        }
    }

    #region LeftBtnClickEvents
    private void btn00_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        btn00.Background = Brushes.Green;
    }
    private void btn01_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        btn01.Background = Brushes.Green;
    }
    private void btn02_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        btn02.Background = Brushes.Green;
    }
    private void btn03_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        btn03.Background = Brushes.Green;
    }
    private void btn04_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        btn04.Background = Brushes.Green;
    }
    private void btn05_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        btn05.Background = Brushes.Green;
    }

    private void btn06_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        btn60.Background = Brushes.Green;
    }
    private void btn07_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        btn07.Background = Brushes.Green;
    }
    private void btn08_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        btn08.Background = Brushes.Green;
    }
    private void btn09_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        btn09.Background = Brushes.Green;
    }

    #endregion LeftBtnClickEvents

    #region RightBtnClickEvent
    private void btn00_RightClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        btn00.Background = Brushes.Red;
    }
    private void btn01_RightClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        btn01.Background = Brushes.Red;
    }
    private void btn02_RightClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        btn02.Background = Brushes.Red;
    }
    private void btn03_RightClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        btn03.Background = Brushes.Red;
    }
    private void btn04_RightClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        btn04.Background = Brushes.Red;
    }
    private void btn05_RightClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        btn05.Background = Brushes.Red;
    }
    private void btn06_RightClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        btn06.Background = Brushes.Red;
    }
    private void btn07_RightClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        btn07.Background = Brushes.Red;
    }
    private void btn08_RightClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        btn08.Background = Brushes.Red;
    }
    private void btn09_RightClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        btn09.Background = Brushes.Red;
    }
    #endregion RightBtnClickEvent
  }
}
```

--
xaml code.

```
<Window x:Class="GOL.frmGame"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GOL"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="frmGame" Height="326.4" Width="388.2" Background="#f2f2f2">
    <Grid x:Name="WindowGrid" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
        <Grid x:Name="btnNavbar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="38" Margin="40,241,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button x:Name="btnNewGen"  Content="New Generation"  Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnLoadGen" Content="Load Generation" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnPlayGen" Content="PLAY"            Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
            <Button x:Name="button1"    Content="Magic"           Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnSave"    Content="Save"            Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnReturn"  Content="Menu"            Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1"/>
        </Grid>

        <Grid x:Name="GameBoard" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="200" Margin="80,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Background="Transparent">

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>

            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>

        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>

        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="btn00" Content="" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Click="btn00_Click" MouseRightButtonUp="btn00_RightClick" DataContext="{Binding IsAlive}"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn01" Content="" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Click="btn01_Click" MouseRightButtonUp="btn01_RightClick" DataContext="{Binding IsAlive}"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn02" Content="" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Click="btn02_Click" MouseRightButtonUp="btn02_RightClick" DataContext="{Binding IsAlive}"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn03" Content="" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Click="btn03_Click" MouseRightButtonUp="btn03_RightClick" DataContext="{Binding IsAlive}"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn04" Content="" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Click="btn04_Click" MouseRightButtonUp="btn04_RightClick" DataContext="{Binding IsAlive}"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn05" Content="" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Click="btn05_Click" MouseRightButtonUp="btn05_RightClick" DataContext="{Binding IsAlive}"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn06" Content="" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="6" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Click="btn06_Click" MouseRightButtonUp="btn06_RightClick" DataContext="{Binding IsAlive}"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn07" Content="" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="7" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Click="btn07_Click" MouseRightButtonUp="btn07_RightClick" DataContext="{Binding IsAlive}"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn08" Content="" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="8" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Click="btn08_Click" MouseRightButtonUp="btn08_RightClick" DataContext="{Binding IsAlive}"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn09" Content="" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="9" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Click="btn09_Click" MouseRightButtonUp="btn09_RightClick" DataContext="{Binding IsAlive}"/>

        <Button x:Name="btn10" Content="" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn11" Content="" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn12" Content="" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn13" Content="" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn14" Content="" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn15" Content="" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn16" Content="" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn17" Content="" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="7" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn18" Content="" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="8" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn19" Content="" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="9" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>

        <Button x:Name="btn20" Content="" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn21" Content="" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn22" Content="" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn23" Content="" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn24" Content="" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn25" Content="" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn26" Content="" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="6" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn27" Content="" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="7" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn28" Content="" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="8" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn29" Content="" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="9" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>

        <Button x:Name="btn30" Content="" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn31" Content="" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn32" Content="" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn33" Content="" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn34" Content="" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="4" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn35" Content="" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="5" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn36" Content="" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="6" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn37" Content="" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="7" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn38" Content="" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="8" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn39" Content="" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="9" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>

        <Button x:Name="btn40" Content="" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn41" Content="" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn42" Content="" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn43" Content="" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="3" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn44" Content="" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="4" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn45" Content="" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="5" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn46" Content="" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="6" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn47" Content="" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="7" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn48" Content="" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="8" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn49" Content="" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="9" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>

        <Button x:Name="btn50" Content="" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="0" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn51" Content="" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn52" Content="" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="2" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn53" Content="" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="3" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn54" Content="" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="4" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn55" Content="" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="5" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn56" Content="" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="6" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn57" Content="" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="7" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn58" Content="" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="8" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn59" Content="" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="9" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>

        <Button x:Name="btn60" Content="" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="0" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn61" Content="" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn62" Content="" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="2" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn63" Content="" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="3" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn64" Content="" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="4" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn65" Content="" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="5" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn66" Content="" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="6" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn67" Content="" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="7" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn68" Content="" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="8" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn69" Content="" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="9" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>

        <Button x:Name="btn70" Content="" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="0" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn71" Content="" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn72" Content="" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="2" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn73" Content="" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="3" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn74" Content="" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="4" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn75" Content="" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="5" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn76" Content="" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="6" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn77" Content="" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="7" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn78" Content="" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="8" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn79" Content="" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="9" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>

        <Button x:Name="btn80" Content="" Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="0" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn81" Content="" Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn82" Content="" Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="2" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn83" Content="" Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="3" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn84" Content="" Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="4" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn85" Content="" Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="5" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn86" Content="" Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="6" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn87" Content="" Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="7" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn88" Content="" Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="8" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn89" Content="" Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="9" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>

        <Button x:Name="btn90" Content="" Grid.Column="9" Grid.Row="0" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn91" Content="" Grid.Column="9" Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn92" Content="" Grid.Column="9" Grid.Row="2" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn93" Content="" Grid.Column="9" Grid.Row="3" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn94" Content="" Grid.Column="9" Grid.Row="4" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn95" Content="" Grid.Column="9" Grid.Row="5" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn96" Content="" Grid.Column="9" Grid.Row="6" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn97" Content="" Grid.Column="9" Grid.Row="7" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn98" Content="" Grid.Column="9" Grid.Row="8" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn99" Content="" Grid.Column="9" Grid.Row="9" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create entire grid with just few lines of XAML code. ;-)

## Using magic of MVVM

Create ViewModel class for managing buttons. Let it have an `ObservableCollection` of your buttons' data. I've also created a variable which sets number of columns of our grid.

```
public ObservableCollection<GridButton> GridButtonList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<GridButton>();
public int GridColumns { get; set; }
```

Then, create basic class for storing data of each button — like background and defined actions for left and right mouse click. It's important to use Properties instead of regular variables, as it'll allow you to use them directly in XAML bindings. You may need to extend those to make use of `PropertyChanged` event, which I'll explain later.

```
class GridButton
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Brush Background { get; set; }
    public ICommand OnLeftClick { get; set; }
    public ICommand OnRightClick { get; set; }
}
```

Next, we can create a View based on **UserControl** for displaying just those buttons.

```
<UserControl ...>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <!-- Binding previously created ViewModel to our View -->
        <ViewModel:ButtonGridViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding GridButtonList}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding GridColumns}" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding Text}" Background="{Binding Background}" Command="{Binding OnClick}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                    <Button.InputBindings>
                        <MouseBinding Gesture="RightClick" Command="{Binding OnRightClick}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                    </Button.InputBindings>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</UserControl>
```

Notice that we'll import all the buttons from the variable `GridButtonList` defined in our ViewModel. It doesn't matter how much buttons you'll have, XAML will **not** change from now on.

I recommend using `UniformGrid` which will automatically arrange items on the plane. You can optionally define both Rows and Columns as a hint for the grid. The upside is that every item will have the same width and height which seems to be perfect for your application.

We're providing collections of objects `GridButton`, which means that every item in `ItemsControl` will be of that type. We're instructing it to use data from `GridButton` class to render `Button` for each item. For standard left click we'll use default `Command` property with appropriate action defined in `GridButton.OnLeftClick`. As for right click, we'll use `InputBindings` where we can define detailed gesture to fire the next action — `GridButton.OnRightClick`. Full list of available Mouse Gestures is in [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouseaction(v=vs.110).aspx). Similar to `MouseBinding` is [`KeyBinding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keybinding(v=vs.110).aspx) which supports firing commands based on keyboard gestures.

## Populating the buttons' collection

The following code will create 81 buttons with individual actions. Thanks to XAML binding each button will have a text inside corresponding to its location in format XxY. Notice that we can use only one loop to create a grid, thanks to **Modulo operator**.

```
GridColumns = 9;

var itemCount = Math.Pow(GridColumns, 2);
for (var i = 0; i < itemCount; ++i)
{
    var btn = new GridButton()
    {
        Text = string.Format("{0}x{1}", i % GridColumns + 1, i / GridColumns + 1),
        OnClick = new RelayCommand<GridButton>((b) =>
        {
            b.Background = Brushes.Green;
        }),
        OnRightClick = new RelayCommand<GridButton>((b) =>
        {
            b.Background = Brushes.Red;
        })
    };
    GridButtonList.Add(btn);
}
```

## Helper classes

I used 2 classes that help make everything work, `RelayCommand` for `Command` support and `ObservableObject` which helps bring our data bindings to life. Both of which I listed below:

```
internal class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChangedEvent(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    #region Fields

    readonly Action<T> _execute = null;
    readonly Predicate<T> _canExecute = null;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of <see cref="DelegateCommand{T}"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">Delegate to execute when Execute is called on the command.  This can be null to just hook up a CanExecute delegate.</param>
    /// <remarks><seealso cref="CanExecute"/> will always return true.</remarks>
    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    /// <param name="canExecute">The execution status logic.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute, Predicate<T> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    #endregion

    #region ICommand Members

    ///<summary>
    ///Defines the method that determines whether the command can execute in its current state.
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="parameter">Data used by the command.  If the command does not require data to be passed, this object can be set to null.</param>
    ///<returns>
    ///true if this command can be executed; otherwise, false.
    ///</returns>
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute((T)parameter);
    }

    ///<summary>
    ///Occurs when changes occur that affect whether or not the command should execute.
    ///</summary>
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    ///<summary>
    ///Defines the method to be called when the command is invoked.
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="parameter">Data used by the command. If the command does not require data to be passed, this object can be set to <see langword="null" />.</param>
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute((T)parameter);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

## Working example

I took a liberty of creating sample project for you to analyse. You can check it out on GitHub: https://github.com/xerif-examples/WPF-ButtonGridTest

I recommend using MVVM to write less code.

*Hope that helps,

~Wiktor*

Comment: This looks pretty much what i'm looking for and i belive it shuld not be to difficult to build mroe funtionality. :)
Thx for a quic and good anwser.
~TobiasOlsson

Comment: I'm glad it helps! If it fully answers your question, you can mark it as accepted answer. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GetValue() function of a UIElement, in this case, a Button, then casting the object returned to the appropriate type, in this case, an int.

```
int row = (int)button.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty);
int col = (int)button.GetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty);
```

You can then use these values in your for loop to do whatever it is you need to do.

Comment: For this sulution to work i asume i have to make an instace of the button controle and build the properitys there.
I have been looking into that but it seams a little messy, probably not to hard to do, but a bit messy for the level i'm currently at.
Correct me if i'm wrong. :)

~TobiasOlsson

Comment: According to your code above, you already have a collection for your buttons, called btnCollection which you could use to iterate through, and you have already defined the Grid.RowProperty and Grid.ColumnProperty of your buttons in XAML. I will say, @Wiktor's solution is elegant and explains how best to use MVVM, the design pattern usually used for WPF, but for a quick and easy solution, you should have little trouble implementing my answer.